# Custom View wrapping its content in a specific child view

Tags: android

Given the following example layout with a custom view "RowWrapperView":

(row_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.android.RowWrapperView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...  >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.example.android.RowWrapperView>
```

The view have an inflated layout (view_row_wrapper.xml) with a LinearLayout with id "R.id.container":

```
public class RowWrapperView extends RelativeLayout {
    public RowWrapperView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public RowWrapperView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public RowWrapperView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public LinearLayout container;
    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_row_wrapper, this);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    }
}
```

(view_row_wrapper.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...  >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- Trying to get the content of the view here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/something_else"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_sender"
            tools:text="Jon Snow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the content of "RowWrapperView" (of row_item.xml) in R.id.container.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Inflater has return type - view, this view you must add to your layout then search it
try this without adding view to layout

```
 private void init() { 
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_row_wrapper, this);
    container = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
}
```

or this with adding to layout

```
 private void init() { 
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_row_wrapper, this);
    addView(view);
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
}
```

Comment: This will inflate correctly the layout R.layout.view_row_wrapper in the custom view.  But how can I get the content of the tag RowWrapperView (in row_item.xml) in the R.id.container?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might do this:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<getChildCount() ; i++) {
            container.add(getChildAt(i));
        }
```

for add all elements to container.

Comment: You mean in the init() ?

Comment: Yes, because in this way you set the elements to container instead the current view.